# How to go back from 'z' to 'a' in casear cipher encryption

Tags: c

I am trying to encrypt a message using casear cipher in C, when i found the character 'z' in the message i am trying to go back in character 'a' (by -=25 ) but it is not going back to character 'a' it is going back to character 'b' i have also tried with -=26 and -=24 but not getting to 'a', any comment will be highly appreciated. Here is my code.........

```
void casear_cipher(char *message);
int main()
{
    char message[] = "Todayzzz is Tuesday";
    printf("Original Message is : '%s'\n", message);

    casear_cipher(message);

    printf("Encrypted Message is: '%s'\n", message);
}

void casear_cipher(char *message)
{
    int i;
    int message_length = strlen(message);
    for(i = 0; i<message_length; i++)
    {
        if(message[i] == 'z' || message[i] == 'Z')
        {
            message[i] -= 25; //<-------------------------Problem is here
        }

        if( (message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z') || (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z') )
        {
            message[i] += KEY;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get comfortable with `ctypes.h`

Comment: @Olaf. I don't think that will fix OP's problem, although it is good advice in general.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Comments are not for answering.

Comment: This is really very basic. Try harder.

Comment: Your implementation is wrong. As this is homework, no solution, but a hint: You don't have to wrap the original message text.

Comment: A piece of paper and a pencil may help here.

Comment: Your code is missing an `else` ... somewhere.

Comment: Hint: the `if(message[i] == 'z' || message[i] == 'Z')` test and the `-= 25` is nonsense, delete this part. The `+= KEY` part is almost correct. You need to handle the case where `message[i] += KEY` is greater than `z` or `Z`. Supposing `KEY = 2` : `A` -> `C`, `B` -> `D`, `X`-> `Z`, `Y`-> `A`.

Comment: Thank you everyone.... i got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get 'a' because your second `if` still runs. The first `if` changes the value to A or a and the second `if` adds the `KEY` value. If you want all z to become a and Z to become A you want to change this to an `else if` like this:

```
if(message[i] == 'z' || message[i] == 'Z')
{
    message[i] -= 25; 
}

else if( (message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z') || (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z') )
{
    message[i] += KEY;
}
```

I think you want something more like this though:

```
if((message[i] >= ('z' - KEY + 1) && message[i] <= 'z') || (message[i] > (('Z' - KEY + 1)) && message[i] < 'Z'))
{
    message[i] -= 26;
    message[i] += KEY;
}

else if((message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'u') || (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'U'))
{
    message[i] += KEY;
}
```

That way whenever any value goes past Z or z it starts from the beginning of the alphabet.

Comment: How do you come to `message[i] >= 'v'`? What if `KEY` is 17 for example?

Comment: Woops my bad I made a dummy key forgot to change it when I posted. I will edit.

Comment: Thank you it was really helpful.